# What is wrong in the following algorithm for computing a hash function using RSA?

Tags: hash, rsa

I'm studying for a cryto exam and have run across this question which has stumped me.

What is wrong in the following algorithm for computing a hash function?

- Take a message $M$,
- generate a random private RSA key $K$.
- Encrypt $M$ with $K$ and
- take the first 240 bits of the result as a hash of $M$

Comment: I would think, it's *extremely* inefficient. Maybe there are better reasons. Also, how do you create a random RSA key if this is supposed to be a hash function? A hash function is always supposed to return the same result for the same input.

Answer (score 11):

Hash functions must be public, so if you want to use RSA as a hash function you should fix $K$. Now let $n$ be the RSA modulus and $H$ denote an RSA hash function. We have

> $$H(M)=H(M+n)$$

so this function is not second preimage and collision resistant.

Also, this system is not first preimage resistant (with known public and private key):

Let $M^k=h \pmod n$ and $h_t$ denote the first $t$ bit of $h$, so $H(M)=h_{240}$.

Now suppose $e$ is the public key and $M'={h_{240}}^e \pmod n$. We have:

> $$H(M')=h_{240}$$

So we found an inverse for this hash function and this is not preimage resistant.

Comment: Do you mean RSA **modulus**  instead of RSA _module_?